# Identify all x-intercepts and all asymptotes of the graph $f(x) = 3\tan(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

It says, using $f(x) = 3\tan(x)$ as a guide, find those things. I know what asymptoes are but not x-intercepts. I don't know how to find and say what they are.

[image: 3 tan x]

Comment: I presume it means where the graph crosses the $x$-axis?

Comment: Hint: Do you know where $\sin(x) = 0$, and why this might be of use?

Comment: I know that $x$ would equal $\pi \space n$ but I don't see how it would be of use.

Comment: What do you get when you multiply both sides of your equation, $3\tan (x) = 0$, by $\cos (x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve $f(x) = 0$, which in this case is the same as finding all $x$ that satisfy $\tan(x) = 0$. Your graph, and periodicity of $x\mapsto \tan(x)$ will give you the answer.